# How to use custom .png-Images instead of mat-icons for a button?

Tags: html, angular, icons

I have implemented two buttons in my Angular application, with which the user can change the displayed language. Now, instead of the two buttons with "German" & "English", I want to use two icons with the respective country flag. First I tried it with the "Mat-Icons", unfortunately there are no suitable icons for my use case. Therefore I downloaded two .png files with the respective country flags from Flaticon, saved them in /assets/icons and would now like to integrate these instead of the mat icons. Unfortunately, I just can't get this to work at all and would therefore appreciate some help - thanks!

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="useLanguage('de')">German</button> 

<button mat-button (click)="useLanguage('de')"><mat-icon>...</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: The code shows the implementation that works. But I want to use my own custom .png files as icons instead of texts (line 1) or the mat icons (line 2). And thats the point I don't know how to handle. 

The two lines of code are only there for illustration, to show with what I have started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tpnll?file=src/styles.css)

Use your images this way

```
<button class="icon-button" (click)="useLanguage('de')">
  <img
    class="icon"
    src="assets/your-path-to-icon"
  />
</button>
```

And these custom styles in global styles -

```
.icon-button{
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-button .icon {
  width: 28px;
}
```